# Can you help translate my Korean name (Kim Hee-Joon) into a Mandarin/Traditional name?

Tags: names

Need help translating my name Hee Joon Kim into Mandarin symbols for a name chop. In Korea, we spell our last name first when writing our name, so I am looking for a translation of " Kim Hee Joon ". Thank you very much.

Comment: I guess 金熙俊.  The surname Kim is surely 金.  Judging from [random Korean/Chinese names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_of_Korean_descent), Hee is most commonly 熙, and Joon is most commonly 俊.  It's not the only possibility, though.

Comment: Becky has the best translation.  If your elders didn't tell you the traditional Kanji for your name, I suggest you use Becky's translation, very meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Korean but I found a K-pop star named [Moon Hee-joon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_Hee-joon) who's official translation is 文熙俊. So, your name's translation is probably 金熙俊。

Answer (score -1):

下午好"金贺俊"， 帅哥！

英俊：handsome

Comment: "贺" isn't similar to "Hee". "Hee" is more similar to 希 or 熙, but turn xī into "hī".